# For positive $x,y$ such that $x+y \leq x^2+y^2$ prove inequality for every real $t \ge 1$ $x^t+y^t \leq x^{t+1}+y^{t+1}$.

Tags: inequality

> For positive $x,y$ such that $x+y \leq x^2+y^2$ prove inequality for every real $t \ge 1$ $x^t+y^t \leq x^{t+1}+y^{t+1}$.

I see that $\frac{(x+y)}{2} \leq \frac {x^{t+1}+y^{t+1}}{(x^t+y^t)}$

Comment: $x+y\ge 2$ is not always true. Just take $y$ close to $0$ and say $x=\frac{3}{2}.$ As to the general problem: one may consider the function $f(t)=\log (x^t+y^t)$ and use it convexity that follows from Cauchy- Swartz together with the observation that $f(2)\ge f(1)$

Comment: Thanks, so I have no idea for this.

Answer (score 2):

It is enough to show that for $x, y > 0$:
$$(x^t+y^t)(x^2+y^2) \le (x^{t+1}+y^{t+1})(x+y)$$

$$\iff x^t+y^t\ge x^{t-1}y+y^{t-1}x$$

which follows from Rearrangement inequality as $x \ge y \iff x^{t-1} \ge y^{t-1}$ for $t \ge 1$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :**
$$x+y\leq (x+y)^2\Rightarrow x+y\geq 1$$
if $x\geq1, y\geq1$ then the inequality is hold. suppose that $0<x<1$ and $y\geq 1$ then,
$$x^t(1-x)\leq y^t(y-1).$$